# Linear non-homogeneous differential equations: adding solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

I am slightly stuck and was hoping someone could clarify about the superposition of solutions to linear, non-homogeneous differential equations.

I was taught that if you have two solutions to a linear equation, then any linear combination of these two solutions will also be a solution.

But surely this cannot be the case. Say I have the differential equation

$L(y)= a(x)\frac{d^2y}{x^2}+b(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+c(x)y=f(x)$ and I have two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, then the sum is not a solution as

$L(y_1+y_2)=L(y_1)+L(y_2)=2f(x)\neq f(x)$

I have a feeling that I have misunderstood something quite basic here...

Comment: Your are confusing iinear vs. [affine transformations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space of solutions of a non-homogeneous linear differential equations is an *affine* space with direction the *vector* space of solutions of the associated *homogeneous* equation.

Indeed, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the inhomogeneous equation, $y_1-y_2$ is a solution of
$$a(x)y''(x)+by'(x)+c(x) y(x)=f(x)-f(x)=0 $$
Conversely, if y_2(x) is a solution of the inhomogeneous equation and $z(x)$ a solution of  the associated homogeneous  equation, it is easy to check $y_1(x)=y_2(x)+z(x)$ is a solution of the inhomogeneous equation.

Thus to completely solve a linear inhomogeneous differential equation you have to:  1) completely solve the linear homogeneous associated equation; 2) find *one* solution of the inhomogeneous equation; 3) add any solution of 1) to the particular solution of 2).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am aware of the method of solving inhomogeneous equations by the complementary function and the partcular integral, however what I am stuck on is that it seems that automatically if an equation is inhomogeneous it is non-linear. Take for example the statement in Wikipedia: 'A linear differential equation is called homogeneous if the following condition is satisfied: If   $\phi (x)$  is a solution, so is  $c\phi (x)$...A linear differential equation that fails this condition is called inhomogeneous' However is this condition not a defining feature of linear equation?

Comment: Perhpas I am confusing a linear operator with a linear equation? Is it perhaps the case that these equations are called linear because they contain only linear operators?

Comment: No it's not a defining feature of a linear equation but of a homogeneous equation (there exists homogeneous non-linear equations). An equation is linear if its homogeneous part is linear, which corresponds to a linear operator. For instance $\;\varphi\mapsto $a(x)\varphi''(x)+b(x)\varphi'(x)+c(x)\varphi(x)$ defines a linear operator on the space of twice differentiable function.

Answer (score 1):

I see that nobody has actually answered your question - and I was looking for the same thing so I'll pitch in.

If you have two solutions to a linear non-homogeneous differential equation, lets call them $y_1$ and $y_2$ then you have no guarantee that $y_1 + y_2$ is a solution.

Proof:

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two solutions to the general nonhomogenous linear differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = a(t)y + b(t)$. Then, the sum $$\frac{dy_1}{dt} + \frac{dy_2}{dt} = a(t)y_1 + b(t) + a(t)y_2 + b(t)$$
can be written as
$$\frac{d(y_1+y_2)}{dt} = a(t)(y_1 + y_2) + 2b(t)$$
which clearly indicates that $y_1 + y_2$ is not a solution to the original ODE unless $b(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a solution to the *homogeneous* system to anything, Since that solution will give zero, f(x) remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will bright things a little

Linear superposition does not mean that two solutions of a linear system can be linear combined to make a new one, but it states that the response of two stimulus in a system is equivalent to the sum of the response of each stimulus individually i.e F(x+a) = F(x) + F(a). One consequence of it is that for homogeneous systems, as Ax = 0, then if you find two solutions x_1 and x_2 that solves the sysyem, then c_1 * x_1 +  c_2 * x_2 will give u another solution.

The proof of it is quite straigthforward:

if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions of a system $Ax=0$, then

\begin{align}
A(c1 * x_1 + c2 * x_2) &= 0 \\
A(c1 * x_1) + A(c2 * x_2) &= 0 &\{\text{superposition principle}\} \\
c1(Ax_1) +c_2(Ax_2) &= 0 &\{\text{homogeneity property of linear systems}\} \\
c1 * 0 + c_2 * 0 &= 0 \\
\end{align}

as $x_1$ and $x_2$ does form a basis for the null space of A.

As was already demonstrated here for non-homogeneous system that is not true.

---

Eithan Joseph Proof (Alternative):

Let $y_11$ and $y_2$ be two solutions to the general non-homogenous linear differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=a(t)y+b(t)$. Then, the sum $\frac{dy_1}{dt}+\frac{dy_2}{dt}=a(t)y1+b(t)+a(t)y2+b(t)$ can be written as

$$\frac{d(y_1+y_2)}{dt}=a(t)(y1+y2)+2b(t)$$

source:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle